# Android in-app billing - Why use Integer.valueOf(0)?

Tags: android, security, in-app-billing, boxing, android-billing

I am implementing in-app billing on my app following this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

The step that actually starts the purchase looks like this:

```
startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
   1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
   Integer.valueOf(0));
```

My question is, why do they use `Integer.valueOf(0)`? What's the harm of using only 0? Is there any security reason I am missing?

The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startIntentSenderForResult(android.content.IntentSender,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int,%20int)) of `startIntentSenderForResult` clearly shows that the method signature takes simple primitive ints. So I don't see a need for that manual boxing.